# How to calculate median of X = 2Z - 3 if question wants you to find pdf and cdf?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

This is one of the questions that appeared on my past-year paper which I am currently trying to solve since finals are coming, the problem states that

**Let A be pdf and B be cdf, of the standard normal variable Z. Let X = 2Z-3**

**Q1: What is the median of X?**

**Q2: Given that Z is standard normal, there is a 68% probability that it lies within one s.d. of its mean. Find this probability where X is within 1 standard deviation of the mean.**

There is no additional information given in this question like **intervals (a,b)**  as I am aware that pdf (probability density function) and cdf (cumulative distribution function) require these intervals.

I have tried $\frac{1}{√(2πσ)}exp(\frac{-1}{2})(\frac{Y-μ}{σ})^2$ to obtain pdf but was unable to continue due to cdf still requiring the intervals.

Can someone explain if there ways to obtain median without using the pdf and cdf with intervals?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I suggest to add Latex to the question. There are some weird symbols right now and we can't tell what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, i reformatted the question, it should be better now

Comment: It's still not clear.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or what you tried would be a big step forward!

Comment: Apologies! I will take note, that was the question I was given so perhaps the questions too wasn't written so clearly. After clarification I was able to rewrite some parts.

Comment: @JJLin My point is that you should *only* write out the question you have been given. You also need to write *more*, such as where you got the problem from or what you tried.

Comment: Thanks, I have done a full review to the question based on your points

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: The median of a Gaussian distribution is equal to its mean.